# Apache reverse proxy context to Tomcat without a context

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache instance and two Tomcat instances. Apache is public facing https://public_url/app1 and https://public_url/app2 and should pass each context to the respective Tomcat instance.

One of the Tomcat instance doesn't have a context i.e. https://ip_address:port and I can't get the traffic to proxy properly with AJP13 or HTTP/S.

```
<Location /app1>
ProxyPass ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/app1 nocanon
ProxyPassReverse ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/app1
</Location>

<Location /app2>
ProxyPass ajp://127.0.0.2:8009/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse ajp://127.0.0.2:8009/
</Location>
```

In the above case app1 works but app2 doesn't as it drops the app2 public context i.e Direct access to backend would give https://url/login/login and so I expect it should appear as https://public_url/app2/login/login but instead 404's on https://public_url/login/login

I've tried replacing the above app2 rule with mod_jk on the basis it supports more complex scenarios but with no better success.

```
worker.list=app2_ajp
worker.app2_ajp.port=8009
worker.app2_ajp.host=127.0.0.2
worker.app2_ajp.type=ajp13

LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JKWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/httpd/mod_jk_log
JkLogLevel debug
JkLogStampFormat  "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkOptions +ForwardURICompatUnparsed +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat +ForwardDirectories

JKMountCopy All
JKMount /app2 app2_ajp
JKMount /app2/* app2_ajp
```

Is it possible to proxy to a Tomcat instance over AJP13 without a context?
Where am I going wrong in the configuration of AJP13 or is there a way with HTTPS proxy?